# Derive the discount bond prices of the Vasicek model by the PDE approach

Tags: bond, short-rate, vasicek

[image]

The question is shown above.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please see here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/46472/bond-price-dynamics-in-the-vasicek-model/46477#46477

Comment: Sorry, I still confused about how to use PDE approach, can u give me some related reference??

Comment: Please see the detailed steps here: https://quantpie.co.uk/srm/vasicek_price_pde.php . PS (and declaration): I contribute to this site and channel

Comment: The question I showed is a(T-t) and b(T-t), Is it the typo mistake?. Or it should be a(t,T) and b(t,T)?

Comment: It should be a function of t and T

Comment: So, it should be exponential -a(t, T)(T-t)-b(t,T)(T-t)r(t)??

Comment: You see two alternative forms: Ae^{-Br} or e^{A-Br}, same result but the A's are different - one is the exponential of the other. You can also write it in terms of remaining maturity, which is the form you had used in your question

Comment: So everything in your question works if you interpret a and b as function of (t, T) or of remaining maturity (T-t). Sign and exponentiation are easy to translate from one form to the other.